# iPhone UI controls

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uikit

Which class is used to create the clickable sections(with > arrow) and the checkbox list on last shot?

[alt text http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Art/navigation_interface.jpg](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Art/navigation_interface.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the UINavigationController.

To create the list with arrows, use the UITableView and set the Accessory "Disclosure indicator" on the cell (in the Interface builder).

The screenshot is from the Settings application though. If you want to create subpanels for settings, you need to use a different approach ([Here is one example](http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=274))

Answer (score 0):

UITableView (UITableViewController).

The checkmarks and arrows are added by changing the [`.accessoryType` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW22) of the cell. To make the table views clickable, implement the `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method in the delegate.

Comment: So there is no built in way to manipulate cell state and I have to implement custom logic with changing accessory image to have checkbox behavior?